# How to skip an update if one of the fields in the document has changed? Cloud Firestore

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, transactions

Given a Firebase Document:

`{ a: "hello", b: False}`

When I do a request:
update {b=True} but only if {a == "hello"}

And in the meanwhile, a is set to "world".

I expect that the document should stay like: {a: "world", b: False}
But what I see is this: {a: "world", b: True}

Is it even possible to drop a Cloud Firestore update request on a document, when the document has been changed in the meanwhile?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include which Firebase data your're using?  It's either Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.  And yes, you can just write the same contents of the database back to the location of the transaction if you don't want anything to change.

Answer (score 0):

What I turned out to do was to not check on 1 field, but to check whether the whole document has changed in the meanwhile and then abort the update action.

from google.api_core.exceptions import FailedPrecondition

```
[...]
    doc_ref = self.client.collection(path).document(id)
    snapshot = doc_ref.get()

    if snapshot.exists:
        if snapshot.get("a") == "hello":
            write_option = self.client.write_option(
                last_update_time=snapshot.update_time
            )
            try:
                doc_ref.update({"b": True}, option=write_option)
            except FailedPrecondition:
                # here you can try again as the document has updated in the meanwhile, so `a` could no longer be "hello"
 [...]
```